# Using ActiveModel::Serializer in Rails - JSON data differs between json and index response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, mongoid, active-model-serializers

I'm using [`active_model_serializers`](https://github.com/josevalim/active_model_serializers) gem to control the serialization data, and seeing some odd behavior. My code looks like so:

#### model & serializer

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :first_name, :type => String
  field :last_name,  :type => String

  def full_name
    first_name + " " + last_name
  end
end

class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :first_name, :last_name, :full_name
end
```

#### controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :html

  def index
    @users = User.all
    respond_with @users
  end
end
```

#### view (app/views/users/index.html.erb)

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    // using a backbone collection to manage data
    App.users = new App.Collections.Users(<%= @users.to_json.html_sage %>);
  });
</script>
```

Now, when I render the view, I see that the `full_name` attribute (generated via method in the model) is missing from my data:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe"
}
```

When I access `/users.json` (I have `resources :users` in my `routes.rb` file), I see the correct JSON:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "full_name": "Jonn Doe"
}
```

I couldn't see what I might be doing wrong - any input will help. thanks.

Comment: Please tag the languages you used instead of useless tags like "mismtach" - I've done it this time for you

Comment: No problem - just a friendly reminder :) It improves syntax coloring and will attract more attention

Comment: Not yet. If you have something, please let me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not using your serializer in the HTML view. Try this:

`App.users = new App.Collections.Users(<%= UserSerializer.new(@users).to_json.html_safe %>);`

The reason for this is that the serializer is picked up in the `respond_with` method, the serializer does [not overwrite](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#getting-the-old-version) your `.to_json` method.

Comment: I have the same problem, but when I applied your solution, it threw exception saying "undefined method `read_attribute_for_serialization' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fdb18ea4ef8>". Is it due to gem versions. I am using AMS 0.7.0 and json 1.7.7 gems.

Comment: @Gagan I had the same issue with missing read_attribute_for_serialization (note I'm not using Mongoid, but not persisted ActiveModel), I had to add this to my class: include ActiveModel::Serialization. That did the trick.

Comment: As well as adding include ActiveModel::Serialization I had to ensure in my gem file that I was using 0.8.1 of AMS gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.8.1'

Answer (score 1):

@Gagan this works for me:

`App.users = new App.Collections.Users(<%= ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(@users).to_json.html_safe %>);`