# ActiveModel::Serializer in Rails - serializer methods ignored in JSON result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I am using [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) to create JSON for my Rails models.

**serializer**

```
class OptionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  self.root = false

  attributes :id

  def test_id
    object.id
  end
end
```

However, the to_json option seems to ignore the method added in OptionSerializer:

```
OptionSerializer.new(Option.find(13)).to_json.html_safe
```

**expected output**

```
{
  "id":      13,
  "test_id": 13
}
```

**actual output**

```
{
  "id": 13
}
```

I have reviewed [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367656/using-activemodelserializer-in-rails-json-data-differs-between-json-and-inde), but that is the only post I can find where someone is experiencing this issue.

I am Running Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 4.0.0.  Thank you for your time.

Any support, input or recommendations would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the attributes list, you should specify test_id as well

```
attributes :id, :test_id
```

Comment: Right in front of my this whole time and I didn't notice it.  Thank you!